# Pasting\extracting files into usr folder

Tags: inkscape

While I have used various distros of linux for some time and like them quite a bit, I still find the linux landscape very confusing and often times not very user friendly.. At least coming from years as a windows user and system admin..

Some time back I installed ubuntu studio on an laptop I have and love it as it windows like and almost feels the same.. At least until you get under the hood a bit..

I am still much the noob with linux for this reason.. 
At any rate, recently I purchased a vinyl cutter and did a search to see if there were any linux programs that might run it.. 
Came across InkCut, which I gather is an extension for Inkscape. 
Acording to the instructions on the inkcut site, I am supposed to extract the files into the inkscape extensions folder and it gave what the path should look like..

Well I spent about a month going through that laptop trying to find that location and just could not locate it.. was about ready to just smash the damn laptop and cursing linux for the constant BS you have to always go thru to set simplest things  up..

After one last search, I managed to locate a folder under the file system usr\shared\inkscape\extensions.. yay.. I thought I finally was there and could finally enjoy my damn cutter.. but heck no.. linux had other plans.. it would not let me extract to that folder.. said I did not have permissions to extract to that folder. *Facepalm* here we go yet again..
spent a few more hours on the web searching.. 
Made sure I had sudo access for that account which I did and do..  but still no go.. what the heck?? Why does linux have to be so darned complicated and frustrating.. ??? What do I Need to do??

I have no clue what to do and am really quite close to just smashing this computer and burning every distro of linux I have and just sticking with windows.. Far fewer problems.. it just works.. Just push a couple buttons and your software is installed and running in most cases.. Yet linux is still promising and probably where I am headed.. if I can ever get it to work and actually make sense..

With linux my experience has been 50/50.. half the time things install thru the software center just fine.. the other times I have to spend way too much time i terminal typing endless lines  and commands  and searching forums and hoping and praying to get timely responses.. some things get responded and resolved in a few days which really kills the fun and excitement of gaining new software and wanting to use it.. and still times when you dont get responses or solutions and never get to enjoy your software you hoped to enjoy..  I have a packet program that I have never been able to get working.. got very vague help .. finally just gave up on it after a couple years  of sporadic tries..

I mean.. I dont mind doing a little extra work and a little tweaking.. but when a little turns into  hours, days or months just to resolve what should be a normal, simple easy or routine process or installation..

I understand the need for security and appreciate its protection.. but sometimes it seems a little over the top or annoying in all of the linux distros I have played with.. Sometimes I would just like to turn all the security off just so I can function freely without restraints.. Would almost be faster and easier to reinstall linux a hundred times over than constantly dealing with the road blocks it throws up.. ugh

I am getting this real love hate relationship with linux.. when it works it is totally awesome.. but when it doesnt it is just a nightmare

---

Wow.. thanks all for the input some good stuff to consider and look over.. 
My problem is that when I had installed ubuntu studio, inkscape was already part of it, I did not install it.. It was not located in the .config folder where the inkcut site recommended extracting its files to.. I never did find a .config folder.. So when I finally found inkscape in the usr/shares folder, I just assumed that is where it needed to go and extract the files there.. I am not strong in the ways of linux so where and why linux puts things and how to locate them gets confusing  and frustrating sometimes..

When I install thru the software center, unlike windows, I have no clue where linux puts stuff.. for the most part.. have to really dig sometimes to find things.. there are a few things I have installed where I got to tell it where I wanted it installed, which I did.. but not inkscape.. it was already there..

Should I just uninstall it(inkscape) and try to reinstall it? And then try to extract inkcut again and see if it is where it needs to be?

Comment: " but sometimes it seems a little over the top or annoying in all of the linux distros I have played with.. " sorry but that is -not- correct and is more of an indication -you- lack knowledge ;-) " /usr is for system read only files installed by the OS. "Sometimes I would just like to turn all the security off just so I can function freely without restraints" Install Windows ;-) And gave a guess what would could happen if you do unset security (hint: same problems Windows faces). No security is as strict as needed (we had decades to perfect security). **But what is the problem we can answer?**

Comment: basically you are running into permission problems as you already assumed . .you can unzip using the sudo command and it will let you copy the files into the directory you want but you may run into another issue  because sudo will copy the files as root and may not be able to be accessed by the program properly .. you may have to change the permissions on the files after copying. So if you are using the tar command to extract just add sudo in front of it. If you are using a GUI "windowed" program then you will need to launch the program with sudo permissions  such as `sudo file-roller`

Comment: The [inkcut sourceforge page](http://inkcut.sourceforge.net/) actually recommends installing into your user's `~/.config/inkscape/extensions/`directory - so no need to mess with the system's `/usr` directory or get tangled up in permissions.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of info, but I have to agree with steeldriver.  It really seems like the issue should be what is the problem with putting it in the users extension folder? Is it missing? Doesn't inkscape find the extension when placed there? There may be a place for a lesson on file management in the root system but it sure doesn't seem like the program wants to go that route.

Answer (score 3):

So you wish to install the InkCut as an extension to inkscape ?

Without knowing either I just did :

- install of inkscape :   go to Launcher bar (move mouse to far left screen and click on that circular Ubuntu icon (Dash) at top of list then type in : `Software` (click on matching icon) ... then search on `inkscape` and do install)
- [download inkcut](http://inkcut.sourceforge.net) :  it downloads to file `~/Downloads/InkCut-1.0.tar.gz`
- now to actual install of inkcut ... from terminal (ctrl-alt-t) issue :

`tar -xzvf ~/Downloads/InkCut-1.0.tar.gz  -C   ~/.config/inkscape/extensions/`

Done !!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you like using the GUI which makes things easier, do this in terminal :

```
sudo nautilus
```

and enter your password when prompted. This will make the file browser have root access and you can now copy files into the /usr structure.

Alternate solution if you're trying to extract a compressed file is

```
sudo file-roller
```

Then open your compressed file and extract.

**NOTE!** Make sure you do not edit or create any files in your home folder while using Nautilus or File Roller with sudo!

Comment: I'd rather you would suggest using command line. Using "sudo" with Nautilus should be considered as bad behaviour and can lead to problems. (edit: the edit suggesting file-roller is better but I would suggest making that the preferred method (but command line would be my 1st choice ;-) )

Comment: This is a good point.  However, I've never found any major issues using Nautilus with sudo.  And for a beginner who has trouble with command lines, the GUI makes things easy when you're just dealing with moving/copying files.

Comment: I can tell you one for sure: there are a couple of files in /home/$USER/ that -must- be owned by $USER and are switched to "root" when you edit them (making logging in crash back to the login screen).

Comment: Very true.  Not something I would do as I'm aware of the permissions change, but good to point out.  Edited and added your point to my answer :)